# Why filter function does not return correct value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and hence the below error might be from a novice.

I have the below complex object and depending on the value of first `array`, I would like to populate a `select` options from "Array of Objects". 
The Values returned from `filter` function is not what I expect, so I request your assistance.

```js
var complexObject = {
  itemList: ["Item1", "Item1", "Item1", "Item1", "Item2", "Item2"],
  itemDetails: [{
      itemList: "List1",
      itemType: "Type1"
    },
    {
      itemList: "List2",
      itemType: "Type2"
    },
    {
      itemList: "List3",
      itemType: "Type3"
    },
    {
      itemList: "List4",
      itemType: "Type4"
    },
    {
      itemList: "ListH",
      itemType: "TypeH",
    },
    {
      itemList: "ListZ",
      itemType: "TypeZ",
    }
  ]

};

function populateItems() {
  var itemListArray = complexObject.itemList.slice();
  var itemCount = itemListArray.length;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < itemCount) {
    if (itemListArray[i] == itemListArray[i + 1]) {
      itemListArray.splice(i, 1);
    } else
      i++;
    itemCount = itemListArray.length;
  }

  var option1List = document.getElementById("option1");
  for (i = 0; i < itemListArray.length; i++) {
    var newOption = new Option(itemListArray[i]);
    option1List.add(newOption);
  }
}

function changeOption2() {
  var selectedOption = document.getElementById("option1").value;
  var selectedType = complexObject.itemList.filter(function(value, index) {
    if (value == selectedOption)
      return (complexObject.itemDetails[index].itemType);
  });

  var option2List = document.getElementById("option2");
  var i = 1;
  while (i < option2List.length)
    option2List.remove(i);

  option2List = document.getElementById("option2");
  for (i = 0; i < selectedType.length; i++) {
    var newOption = new Option(selectedType[i]);
    option2List.add(newOption);
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="populateItems()">
  <p>Option 1:</p>
  <select id="option1" onchange="changeOption2()">
    <option>Select</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>

  <p>Option2:</p>
  <select id="option2">
    <option>Select</option>
  </select>
<body>
```

Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

[See filter docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
You must return a boolean value inside your filter callback. It will filter out elements of the array if the function returns false and keep it if it returns true. Since you are not returning a boolean value but a string, it will return true since javascript sees a non-null or non-undefined value as `true`.

You might want to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead.

try this:

```css
var selectedType=complexObject.itemList.reduce(function(accumulator, value, index) {
  if (value==selectedOption) accumulator.push(complexObject.itemDetails[index].itemType);
  return accumulator;
}

, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the filter function takes a test, and then returns all the elements that pass the test. ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) so your code would not return the item type, but rather the selected item from item list.  You probably want to do something more like this

```
var selectedType = complexObject.
    itemDetails[complexObject.itemList.findIndex(elm => elm == selectedOption)];
```

([findIndex docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex))

Alternatively you could use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function, but that would return and array around the selected item type, and it looks like you mainly want to do a lookup operation. You may even want to consider converting `itemDetails` into an object structured like this

```
{ 
    "Item1": {
      itemList: "List1",
      itemType: "Type1"
    }
}
```

That way you could find the type by just checking

```
return complexObject.itemDetails[selectedOption].itemType
```

Answer (score 0):

You want objects from "itemDetails" array but you are filtering "itemList",in JavaScript filter function just return object from the same array that's why you see the result ("Item1", "Item1", "Item1", "Item1") instead of ("Type1", "Type2", "Type3", "Type4"), my advice is that you use a generic for loop like this:

```
var selectedType=[];

for(var i=0;i<complexObject.itemList.length;i++){
    var value = complexObject.itemList[i];
    if (value == selectedOption){
        selectedType.push(complexObject.itemDetails[i].itemType);
    }
}
```